# Cannot decode special character when using `IOUtils.toString(containerRequestContext.getEntityStream(),"UTF-8"); `

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy

I use IOUtils.toString(containerRequestContext.getEntityStream(),"UTF-8"); to get the entity stream and use IOUtils to transfer it into string. However, when meeting with some special character like "{" , "[" and etc, IOUtils cannot decode them, only english and numbers and "&" can be decode.

The content of the entity decoded by IOUtls is as following

```
S=9&X=5&R=5&command=%5B%7B++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R98542%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+4122.54%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+9547.76%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+12548.69%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+521456%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+6412+++++++%7D%2C+++++++%7B+++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R652485%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+95482.36%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+7845.85%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+9847.37%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+741785%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+6482+++++++%7D%2C++++++%7B+++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R742545%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+16982.93%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+85623.17%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+4872.27%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+34528%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+342+++++++%7D++%5D+
```

The primitive form data is as below:
|field|value|
|-|-|
|S|9|
|X|5|
|R|5|
|command|(text of a json array)|

The value of "command" is shown as below:

```
[
{          
"zoneCode": "R98542",           
"targetPosX": 4122.54,           
"targetPosY": 9547.76,           
"targetPosZ": 12548.69,           
"power": 521456,           
"duration": 6412       
},       
{          
"zoneCode": "R652485",          
"targetPosX": 95482.36,           
"targetPosY": 7845.85,           
"targetPosZ": 9847.37,           
"power": 741785,           
"duration": 6482       
},      
{           
"zoneCode": "R742545",           
"targetPosX": 16982.93,           
"targetPosY": 85623.17,           
"targetPosZ": 4872.27,           
"power": 34528,           
"duration": 342       
}  
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to decode them? Is this in GET URL?

Comment: Because I want to decode the jsonarray string, and transfer it into a Java jsonarray. But first of all, the jsonarray string should be decoded correctly. And In this case, the character "{" and "[" cannot be decoded.

Comment: They are in the entity of POST message.

Comment: Can you add the method of your controller/ webservice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also do a URL Decode. Import the `java.net.URLDecoder` package and use the 
`URLDecoder.decode(string, encoding)` method.

See an example below (byteToString variable is the text from your question):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String byteToString = "S=9&X=5&R=5&command=%5B%7B++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R98542%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+4122.54%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+9547.76%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+12548.69%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+521456%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+6412+++++++%7D%2C+++++++%7B+++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R652485%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+95482.36%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+7845.85%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+9847.37%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+741785%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+6482+++++++%7D%2C++++++%7B+++++++++++%22zoneCode%22%3A+%22R742545%22%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosX%22%3A+16982.93%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosY%22%3A+85623.17%2C+++++++++++%22targetPosZ%22%3A+4872.27%2C+++++++++++%22power%22%3A+34528%2C+++++++++++%22duration%22%3A+342+++++++%7D++%5D+";
        String urlDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(byteToString , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        System.out.println(urlDecoded);
    }
```

Result:

```
S=9&X=5&R=5&command=[{          "zoneCode": "R98542",           "targetPosX": 4122.54,           "targetPosY": 9547.76,           "targetPosZ": 12548.69,           "power": 521456,           "duration": 6412       },       {           "zoneCode": "R652485",           "targetPosX": 95482.36,           "targetPosY": 7845.85,           "targetPosZ": 9847.37,           "power": 741785,           "duration": 6482       },      {           "zoneCode": "R742545",           "targetPosX": 16982.93,           "targetPosY": 85623.17,           "targetPosZ": 4872.27,           "power": 34528,           "duration": 342       }  ]
```